# MutationObserver doesn't trigger when text changes

Tags: javascript

I have a simple tag on my html page

```
<div id="myid">My text</div>
```

Im new to JavaScript. I need that MutationObserver detect when text changes in "My text"
here is my JavaScript code

```
var target = document.querySelector("#myid");

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        console.log(mutation.type);
    });
});

var config = { 
    childList: true, 
    attributes: true, 
    characterData: true, 
    subtree: true, 
    attributeFilter: ["myid"], 
    attributeOldValue: true, 
    characterDataOldValue: true 
}

observer.observe(target, config);

observer.disconnect();
```

Comment: _"I need ... detect when text changes"_ - Why? And why a heavy-weight `MutationObserver`? Whose changing that text? Can you control that part? Is there maybe an event that triggers that text change?

Comment: Agreed with previous comment, if you're really " new to JavaScript" chances are very high you don't need a MutationObserver at all. I'm not new anymore but I never used it outside of bug/hack hunt. Now regarding your code, it does call  `observer.disconnect()` right after you initialized the Observer. That doesn't let it much time to observe anything, actually it lets it absolutely no time at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect changes of a text field you can simply use `onChange` event, for example:

```
<input type="text" id="myid"/>

<script>
    let sel = document.getElementById('myid');
    sel.addEventListener ("change", function (data) {
       console.log(data.currentTarget.value);
    });
</script>
```

`MutationObserver` is good to use when you want to subscribe on DOM changes - like attribute changes etc. That's why youк code doesn`t work, because you don't have any changes related to DOM structure.
See example with additionally adding new attribute:

```
const targetNode = document.getElementById('myid');

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    // Use traditional 'for loops' for IE 11
    for(const mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
            console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
        }
        else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
            console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
        }
    }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

//MODIFY THE ATTIBUTE TO SEE THE CHANGE
targetNode.style["color"] = "red";
```

If you want to play with it, please see: https://jsfiddle.net/a0vdxt5n/40/

Comment: "you don't have any changes related to DOM structure". But, a text node change is a change to the DOM, and it should trigger the mutation observer (as long as `childList: true`). [A modified version of your example which demonstrates this](https://jsfiddle.net/p6e0cosm/)

Comment: Of course everything is preserved in DOM can be detected using it, I meant that it is possible to configure mutation config in a way you want, but it is a bad way to detect changes in a text field using `MutationObserver`. It is commonly used for subscribing on changes of "real DOM changes", which is not really easy using vanilla JS. But instead, vanilla JS propose good event for detecting the "simple" changes in the field.

Comment: While the askers question isn't particularly clear about how the change occurs, they do specifically show that it's a `<div>` that's changing, rather than any form of input element, so regular event listeners aren't really relevant here.